# How to execute XQuery update/delete queries through XQilla in linux through commandline

Tags: java, xquery

I am using XQuery in my JAVA project for managing [like select/update/delete] XML files. To run the xqueir's im using XQILLA in Linux.

Here i got a problem in executing the update/delete queries through xqilla.

The query is:
insert nodes  into doc("contact.xml")//Directory/Contacts/Contact[@id = 16311]

I have placed the above query in "test1" file and ran with the following commnad:
xqilla -u test1

and i got an error like:
error: syntax error, unexpected nodes, expecting  [err:XPST0003]

can anybody tell me how to run the xquery update/delete queries through XQILLA in Linux environment.

Is any settings needed in XQilla for executing XQUERY update/delete queries from commandline.

It's an urgent & need the solution for it.

Answer (score 0):

Your query syntax is wrong. What nodes do you want to insert? I guess you only noted *where* to insert them, not *what*.

Try something like

```
insert node <your>XML</<your> into doc("contact.xml")//Directory/Contacts/Contact[@id = 16311]
```

Have a look at [some documentation on XQuery Update](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Updates#insert) (or [XQilla's](http://xqilla.sourceforge.net/XQueryUpdate)).